# How to check if ip is up or down using python

Tags: python, server, ip, host

I want to check if my ip server is on or no for a project but using python can someone help me?

Comment: What' do you mean by ip server?

Comment: What kind of server?  web?  ftp?  ssh?

Comment: @JohnGordon it's a minecraft server

Comment: Do you just want to check if the host _exists_?  Or do you want to check that minecraft is _successfully running_ on the host?

Comment: i want to check that minecraft is successfully running on the host pls

Answer (score 0):

See below code - paste the UrL link which you want to check if status code is 200 it is accessible else not accessible means site is down .

```
import requests
page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akki')

if page.status_code==200:
    print("Server is up ")
else:
    print("Server is down")
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to ckeck a DNS or numeral ip of a normal server(not a website), if you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
import os 
my_hostname='142.251.40.206'
ip_UP  = True if os.system("ping -c 1 " + my_hostname) == 0 else False
print(ip_UP)
```